# How to show that $\ker d\pi_x=T_x(\pi^{-1}(\pi(x)))$?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

> If $\pi:M\to N$ be a submersion then how to show that $\ker d\pi_x=T_x(\pi^{-1}(\pi(x)))$?

I have another question about submersions:

> It is true that $N$ can be thought as submanifold of $M$?

Comment: Show that one inclusion relation is satisfied and then use rank-nullity law. I’m not sure what you mean by submanifold on the last sentence since $N$ is not necessarily a subset of $M$.

Comment: I believe that your second question is actually asking if there is necessarily a global section $\sigma\colon N\to M$ (i.e., a smooth map with $\pi\circ\sigma(p)=p$ for all $p\in N$). When $\pi$ is, for example, a vector bundle, the answer is yes. But try the example of the Hopf map $\pi\colon S^3\to S^2$.

Comment: For another counterexample to your second question, consider $\pi : \mathbb R \to S^1$ given by $\pi(t) = (\cos(2\pi t),\sin(2 \pi t))$.

Comment: Thank you @LeeMosher. I really don't know why $d\pi_p(X_p)=0\Rightarrow X_p\in T_p(\pi^{-1}(\pi(p)))$?

Comment: Do you know the inverse function theorem? If so then the comment of @Sou gives the answer.

Comment: @LeeMosher, I solved this question and I don't know what is the usage of *inverse function theorem* here?!!!

Comment: Maybe based on your answer to say that the function is a smooth map on the preimage means that we know that the preimage is an embbeded submanifold which is actually the consequence of IFT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** $\pi{\big|_{\pi^{-1}(\pi(x))}}$ is a constant smooth map that sends all its domain to $\pi(x)$, for all $x\in M$.